# Delivering precompiled Handlebars Template on demand via JSON

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to deliver `Handlebars` templates to my `Ember.js` application on demand via `Ajax`-request. I'm able to compile it on the server and I'm also able to deliver something like the following output (`function`) as `String`:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["authentication"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
this.compilerInfo = [2,'>= 1.0.0-rc.3'];
helpers = helpers || Ember.Handlebars.helpers; data = data || {};
  var buffer = '', stack1, hashTypes, options, helperMissing=helpers.helperMissing, escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;


  data.buffer.push("<h1>Hooray! It works!</h1>\r\n");
  hashTypes = {};
  options = {hash:{},contexts:[depth0],types:["ID"],hashTypes:hashTypes,data:data};
  data.buffer.push(escapeExpression(((stack1 = helpers.outlet),stack1 ? stack1.call(depth0, "main", options) : helperMissing.call(depth0, "outlet", "main", options))));
  return buffer;

});
```

This is exactly the `String` that I'm able to get from the received `JSON` object. Now, I want to add this precompiled template to the `Ember.TEMPLATES` object like this:

```
if(typeof data.template === 'string' && data.template != '') {
                  var escapedTemplateString =
                      data.template.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\\t/g, "\\t");

                  Ember.TEMPLATES[templateName] = Ember.Handlebars.template(new Function(escapedTemplateString));
                }
```

But this wraps the whole 'stringified' function into another `anonymous function(){}` and I get no template. If I unpack the 'stringified' function with `eval`, then the template is `undefined`...

Does anybody know how to get a `function` without any wrap up from a 'stringified' function?
Thanks a lot for your time in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I forgot to declare my `Ajax` request as `async: false` so that the rendering process would wait for the template to be loaded.

also, I changed the function call from `eval( escapedTemplateString )` to `eval( "(" + escapedTemplateString + ")" )`

--> everything's working great now